# Rspec - view test and html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Can somebody explain my why this test can't be passed?
I'm simply test article view with html content. 
In view i display content through html_safe

```
.article_content
  = @article.content.html_safe
```

in my test i have something like below:

```
 context 'shows actual article' do
        before(:all) { @article = FactoryGirl.build(:article, id: 1, 
        content: '<h2>aaaaa ddd bbb</h2>') }

        before(:each) { render }

    it 'show content' do
      render.should have_selector('div.article_content',text: @article.content.html_safe)
    end
```

after that my test fails:

```
Failure/Error: render.should have_selector('div.article_content',text: @article.content.html_safe)
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "div.article_content" with text "<h2>aaaaa ddd bbb</h2>"
but there were no matches. Also found "\naaaaa ddd bbb\n", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

but when i drop html tags from factory object's content test pass.
i don't know why html tags are chane to '\n'. in browser all looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The has_selector/have_selector matcher matches on the text which is actually visible - and the text that shows up on the page is `aaaaa ddd bbb` rather than `<h2>aaaaa ddd bbb</h2>'`

Comment: ok , i understand, thank you. But is there a way to strip tags from builded object to make a test pass? or can i only do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling a lot with the same issue I've came to following solution:

Include this at the bottom of your `spec` File:

```
def strip_tags(string)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(string)
end
```

Now you can test for things like this:

```
expect(page).to have_content(strip_tags(I18n.t('my_text.applicant_html')))
```

Now even if your translation includes some html tags it will check correctly.